# C# .Net Finderprint Program

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint

I need to made a customized program for myself, for which I'd like to unlock a folder using my laptop built-in finger print validation sensor. I want to know if it's possible to use laptop (HP Envy 14 ) sensor for customized purpose ?
If so how can I get started ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using an SDK

Here is one company which do an SDK for the .Net language

[Verifinger](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html)

Just to point out that I don't think this SDK is hardware specific.

> "Compact portable software. FingerCell is designed for easy
>   implementation into very various and specific applications. The
>   algorithm's source code is sensor independent; therefore it can be
>   ported to various platforms and hardware. "

Comment: This uses additional hardware, I'm interested in using my laptop integrated sensor

Comment: Where does it say that this SDK is hardware specific?

Comment: Well, I was looking for some API which allow me to customize the usage of laptop fingerprint.